# WooCommerce trouble extending WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to extend the `WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler` class of the WooCommerce Stripe Gateway plugin in order to examine the webhook request body.

Although I'm extending the class and changing the function `check_for_webhooks`, the parent function is still being called. I've tried several alternatives, such as removing the parent action and adding mine. I'd prefer to simply extend the class, but, after a day of Googling and tweaking, I've hit a wall.

Would love some guidance on this!

**Parent Class file: class-wc-stripe-webhook-handler.php**

```
class WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler extends WC_Stripe_Payment_Gateway {
    /**
     * Delay of retries.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $retry_interval;

    /**
     * Is test mode active?
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $testmode;

    /**
     * The secret to use when verifying webhooks.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $secret;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     * @version 4.0.0
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->retry_interval = 2;
        $stripe_settings      = get_option( 'woocommerce_stripe_settings', array() );
        $this->testmode       = ( ! empty( $stripe_settings['testmode'] ) && 'yes' === $stripe_settings['testmode'] ) ? true : false;
        $secret_key           = ( $this->testmode ? 'test_' : '' ) . 'webhook_secret';
        $this->secret         = ! empty( $stripe_settings[ $secret_key ] ) ? $stripe_settings[ $secret_key ] : false;

        add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_stripe', array( $this, 'check_for_webhook' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Check incoming requests for Stripe Webhook data and process them.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     * @version 4.0.0
     */
    public function check_for_webhook() {
        error_log('DEBUG BOO!!!! Entered parent function');
        if ( ( 'POST' !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
            || ! isset( $_GET['wc-api'] )
            || ( 'wc_stripe' !== $_GET['wc-api'] )
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $request_body    = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
        $request_headers = array_change_key_case( $this->get_request_headers(), CASE_UPPER );

        // Validate it to make sure it is legit.
        if ( $this->is_valid_request( $request_headers, $request_body ) ) {
            $this->process_webhook( $request_body );
            status_header( 200 );
            exit;
        } else {
            WC_Stripe_Logger::log( 'Incoming webhook failed validation: ' . print_r( $request_body, true ) );
            status_header( 400 );
            exit;
        }
    }
/* other functions... */
}

new WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler();
```

**Child Class**

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/includes/class-wc-stripe-webhook-handler.php';

class BSD_WC_SCSP_Stripe_Webhook_Handler extends WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function check_for_webhook() {
        error_log('DEBUG WOO-HOO!!!! Entered child version.');
        if ( ( 'POST' !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
            || ! isset( $_GET['wc-api'] )
            || ( 'wc_stripe' !== $_GET['wc-api'] )
        ) {
            return;
        }

        $request_body    = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
        $request_headers = array_change_key_case( $this->get_request_headers(), CASE_UPPER );

        // Validate it to make sure it is legit.
        if ( $this->is_valid_request( $request_headers, $request_body ) ) {
            error_log('DEBUG: TO-DO Now examine the request_body');
            $this->process_webhook( $request_body );
            status_header( 200 );
            exit;
        } else {
            WC_Stripe_Logger::log( 'Incoming webhook failed validation: ' . print_r( $request_body, true ) );
            status_header( 400 );
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Following Sebo's suggestion, I modified my constructor to include an `add_action` call, like so:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_stripe', array( $this, 'check_for_webhook'), 99 );           
}
```

I confirmed my hook is being added with the following:

```
$hook_name = 'woocommerce_api_wc_stripe';
global $wp_filter;
error_log( print_r($wp_filter[$hook_name], true) );
```

However, the function is still not being called. Note: I tried both the parent function name of check_for_webhook and then renaming mine and adding it as an action. In both cases, it was not called. Also tried removing the parent hook with remove_action; no dice.

**EDIT #2:** `WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler` is instantiated at the launch of the WooCommerce Stripe Gateway plugin. That plugin is launched after all other plugins are loaded: `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_gateway_stripe_init' );`

**EDIT #3 / FINAL WORKING CLASS:** Thanks to Sebo's guidance, and the help of a colleague named Dung Nguyen Tien, this is now working. The key was to add the child version of check_for_webhook with a priority of 9. Here's the full class:

```
if (!class_exists('BSD_WC_SCSP_Stripe_Webhook_Handler')) :

    class BSD_WC_SCSP_Stripe_Webhook_Handler extends WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            // child filter
            add_action('woocommerce_api_wc_stripe', array($this, 'check_for_webhook'), 9);
        }

        public function check_for_webhook() {
            error_log('DEBUG WOO-HOO!!!! Entered child version.');
            if (('POST' !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
                || !isset($_GET['wc-api'])
                || ('wc_stripe' !== $_GET['wc-api'])
            ) {
                return;
            }

            $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $request_headers = array_change_key_case($this->get_request_headers(), CASE_UPPER);

            // Validate it to make sure it is legit.
            if ($this->is_valid_request($request_headers, $request_body)) {
                error_log('DEBUG: TO-DO Now examine the request_body');
                $this->process_webhook($request_body);
                status_header(200);
                exit;
            } else {
                WC_Stripe_Logger::log('Incoming webhook failed validation: ' . print_r($request_body, true));
                status_header(400);
                exit;
            }
        }

    }

endif; // class_exists check

new BSD_WC_SCSP_Stripe_Webhook_Handler();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parent class will be called regardless of what you do because most parts of WordPress & Woocommerce are deeply connected between each other not only using OOP but WP action and filter hooks as well.

What you could do to achieve your goal would be to use WordPress add_action function (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Using this function you can hook to the action in your parent class constructor, like this(untested):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_stripe', array( $this, 'my_check_for_webhook' ), 99 );
```

Where $this is the reference to the class holding "my_check_for_webhook" function, the 3rd parameter 99 will decide when your function is due to run as there may be multiple functions tied to the same hook.

Best,
Sebo

Comment: Thanks @sebo. I gave that a shot but no luck. In a nutshell, I confirmed my action is being added, but still not being called. I updated my question with the details.

Comment: hmm where is your class WC_Stripe_Webhook_Handler beeing instantiated? Is it maybe in some late hook? Because that would keep your callback from firing as the chain has already run but it would still be in the $wp_filter global.

Comment: It's instantiated as part of the init function of the main plugin itself. That plugin, in turn, is added after all plugins are loaded: `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_gateway_stripe_init' );` For fun, I tried a few more related things. Updated post with EDIT #2.

Comment: is your plugin only working if you have that run_bsd_wc_scsp_last function in there? Because usually you should let WordPress decide which plugins to load in which order and in your plugin use the third parameter on your add_action and add_filter calls which controls the order of when your hook will be fired.

so in your example: ```add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_stripe', array( $this, 'check_for_webhook'), 99 );```

anything that would be added with less than 99 to the same hook will run before your function.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood your earlier statement about the 99 priority. I forgot 99 essentially meant last! Problem is resolved. Will remove the extraneous info from my question, post the final code, and mark your response as the answer. THANK YOU!